# How do I get the new_session_path(resource_name) to work using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What should i add/ remove from my routes.rb to make sure the link below works?

My view (sign in link)

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

My routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do 
    root to: 'static_pages#home'
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end`
```

The URL that results from the view is '/sessions/new.user'
I get the following error in the rendered view.

Template is missing

```
Missing template sessions/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :rtf, :pdf], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/toad/Code/version1h/edwave/app/views" * "/Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise routes are nested inside a resource. So the path should be

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
```

Comment: i get this error. undefined local variable or method `new_users_session_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f95944ad360>:0x007f95952a2d80>

Comment: But you do have `session_path(resource_name)`, so I would expect there to be a `new_session_path(resource_name)` but I haven't been able to find one. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this for people who would stumble upon this issue.

In addition to @Santhosh answer, you'll need to specify the method as well for the link to work, that's what fixed the issue for me, so it'll be like this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path, method: :get %>
```

I hope this is helpful for some people!